# Узнать результат отправки в gnookii

Tags: bash, shell

Как на bash или shell после выполнения команды "echo df | gnokii --sendsms 73459045567" проверить отправку смс? Я имею в виду записать результат выполнения в переменную и затем посмотреть присутствует ли там ключевое слово: "succeeded". Так как он в терминале показывает текст: "Send succeeded!". Я пытался записать в переменную, но почему-то он возвращает в любом случае пустоту.

Comment: Прикрепите, пожалуйста, пример кода, чтобы было видно, что вы пытались сделать и что делали не так.

Answer (score 1):

Сложно сказать, в чём конкретно у вас была ошибка.

1. Не понял, что такое `my`, но давно не писал на баше, может там что-то новое ввели.
2. При присваивании переменные указываются без знака доллара.
3. Пробелов вокруг `=` при присваивании быть не может.
4. gnokii при ошибке вываливает всё не в stdout, а в stderr, это стоит учитывать и перенаправлять.
5. Дальше вообще какой-то PHP пошёл. Такое ощущение, будто я не понял, что вам нужно.

Однако, вот этот код у меня работает:

```
msg="Yo nigga wazzup?"
phone="79001234567"
result=$(echo $msg | gnokii --sendsms $phone 2>&1)

if [[ $result == *"succeeded"* ]]; then
    echo "Успешная отправка"
else
    echo -e "Ошибка отправки на номер $phone \n"
fi
```

Comment: *может там что-то новое ввели* ­— не ввели. это автор вопроса попытался придумать новый язык «perl-i-sh».

Answer (score 0):

```
my $result = `echo $msg | gnokii --sendsms $phone`;  
if ($result=~/succeeded/){  
   print "успешная отправка"  
}else{  
   print "Ошибка отправки на номер ".$phone."\n";  
}
```

Но у меня почему-то в переменной $result пустота в любом случае.